# Is there any way to get event when user switch between the login options in Windows Logon Screen by C#

Tags: c#, credential-providers

I want to run the Windows Service which get notification when user switch between different options on Windows Logon Screen (in lock or logoff mode).

If I create Custom Credential Provider, raise the event when select/deselect the custom provider, but I need to handle it for any options.

Comment: Legally - no. You can try to place a hook on ICredentialProviderCredential::SetSelected methods of all loaded Credential Providers...